# Add all elements in JSON for a key

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a json file:

```
Key = 1, Element1 = 5, Element2 = 10
Key = 2, Element1 = 10, Element2 = 12
Key = 3, Element1 = 2, Element2 = 22
```

I want to generalize this day for each key in D3.js to something like this:

```
Key = 1, Value = 15
Key = 2, Value = 22
Key = 3, Value = 24
```

I am not sure how do I do that in D3.js!

I understand that I have to iterate through the data first, then iterate through each row, something like this:

```
data=d3.json("xxxx").then(function(data){
    data.forEach(function(d){
        d.map(obj => ([
            obj['Key'],
            Object.entries(obj)
              .filter(item => (item[0]!='Key'))
              .reduce((total, item)=> (total+item[1]),0)
          ]))
})});
```

I am not sure how to proceed beyond this

Comment: Can you `console.log(data)`? I believe outer `forEach` is not needed

Comment: I don't have anything even if I remove forEach

Comment: `data.map(d => ({ Key: d.Key, Value: d3.sum(Object.values(d)) - d.Key }))` will do.